# sum of divisors for given range of numbers from 1 to n

Tags: divisor-sum

we are given a function F(n) for a number n which is defined as sum of the divisors of n (including 1 and n) ... now given an integer N we have to calculate
G(n) = F(1) + F(2) + F(3) + ..... + F(n)...
is there any formula for it???
i saw "Peter Gustav Lejeune Dirichlet " formula that can be used while surfing the net...can this be used??if yes, please provide an explanation for this formula??if no, then provide another method that can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\left(k,n\right)$ denotes the cardinality of $\left\{ i\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,n\right\} \mid k\text{ divides }i\right\} $
then $G\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kf\left(k,n\right)$. Here $f\left(k,n\right)=\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ so $G\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\times\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$.

Take a number, $3$ for instance, and wonder in what $F\left(i\right)$
it will turn up as a term. This is the case if $3$ is a divisor of
$i$. Here $f\left(3,n\right)=\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor$ expresses the number of times that
$3$ turns up as a term of $G\left(n\right)$

**Edit**:

Let say that $X_{k,i}=1$ if $k|i$ and $X_{k,i}=0$ otherwise.

Then
for $i\leq n$ we have $F\left(i\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\times X_{k,i}$.
So $G\left(n\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}F\left(i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\times X_{k,i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}k\times X_{k,i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{k,i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$

Comment: ok i got it...but can u provide any proof for it??can this formula be used for only a single number??

Comment: Is this (edit answer) enough for you?

Comment: i think so...thanks a lot...u made it much more easier than i thought

Comment: Yes, so this is clearly computed in O(n) by above summation, but how do we compute this is O(sqrt(n))? In some programming problems, we require it to compute this sum faster...please share ideas if any :)